# How do you remove old Windows Vista Backups?

Tags: windows-vista, backup, windows-backup

I've been backing up my Vista box using Complete PC backup for quite a while now, and I was just wondering how it is that you remove old backups when your backup drive is to full for another backup.

I recently received the following error:

> The backup did not complete
>   successfully.
>
> An error occurred.  The following
>   information might help you resolve the
>   error:
>
> There is not enough space to save the
>   backup files.  Free up disk space or
>   change your backup settings.
>   (0x81000005)

I don't see anything in the settings for the backup to change this.  Do I have to mount the backup to delete an old backup?  If so where is that file located?

> **Update** Posted my question [here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistarepair/thread/e6d07004-42a7-4e6a-97c5-e5e6394d8ab0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was dumb.  Pretty strait forward that.

On your backup drive look for a folder with the name of your computer (Start->Computer->Right click select properties)

Inside this directory here will be directories with a name format similar to:

> Backup Set YYYY-MM-DD <6 digits>

Additionally on the drive, there may be a directory called **WindowsImageBackup\<your-computer-name>** and this will contain directories with the same name format as above.

Based on the date, delete the old backups.